# Checking if a site is set to sessions

Tags: php, session

I have 2 websites. Now I want to login a user on `my second website` only if `my first website` has a logged in session.

For Example:

```
$checkSiteLogin = //check if my first website has a logged in user and return the $_SESSION['id'] or false if not.
if(!$checkSiteLogin)
    $_SESSION['id'] = $checkSiteLogin
```

Comment: so ... you want your first site to essentially login the user on the second site? I'm sure some kind of javascript shenanigans and/or redirecting to a special sub-page with some kind of token could do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's really what you want but as you show in your example, you want to check if your user has already or not a login session opened in your first site. Then, with the result of your test, login the user on your second website.

First, to check if there is already a session, you need to use the function `isset` to ensure that there is an existing id session like this :

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
  //There is an existing id session so log the user on your second website
} else {
  //Create a new session id
  $_SESSION['id'] = //id session
}
```

Remember, when you use session supervariables, you have to put at the beginning of your scrip, the command `session_start();`

Hope it will help you partially.
Good luck !

Comment: Am sorry but this won't do the work. Your code only checks if there is an existing session on the second website and not the first, so even if there is any existing session in the first website, it will always return false